# swiftUI I want to process my app in the background (background proccessing)

Tags: swift, background, swiftui, background-process, draggesture

I always want to get the x and y coordinate touched of my fingertip.

For example, I also want to get the coordinates when using another app. So I want to process the code below in the background.

It seems good to use background processing in background mode, but I'm not sure

Did everyone any idea? Many thanks!

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var word: String = ""
    
    @State var xPos: CGFloat = 0
    @State var yPos: CGFloat = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        ZStack{
            Image(systemName: "")
                .resizable()
                .padding()
                .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .global).onChanged {
                    dragGesture in
                    self.xPos = dragGesture.location.x
                    self.yPos = dragGesture.location.y
                    
                    print(self.xPos,self.yPos)
                    print(dragGesture.translation)
                }
                .onEnded {dragGesture in
                    self.xPos = dragGesture.location.x
                    self.yPos = dragGesture.location.y
                    print("Last",self.xPos,self.xPos)
                    print("Last",dragGesture.translation)
                })
            
            VStack{
                HStack{
                    Text("\(xPos)")
                    Text("\(yPos)")
                }
                VStack {
                    TextField("please write", text: $word)
                        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())  
                        .padding()  
                    
                    Text("\(word)")
                    
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}






struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```